# Cursor to Query statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am inserting into TABLE_A as given below.

```
INSERT 
       INTO Table_A (house_id,
                    house_key_nbr,
                    mnty_code,
                    split) 
     SELECT wcp.id,
            ld.ld_ln_id, 
            ld.ld_mnty,           
            ROUND((ld.ld_ln_bal/wla.LOAN_AMT) * 100,2) split
       FROM table_B ld,
                 table_C cc,
                 TABLE_D wcp, 
                 TABLE_E wla    
      WHERE cc.conv_id         = I_conv_id
        AND cc.ev_id           = wcp.ev_id 
        AND cc.client_plan_nbr = ld.plan_id
        AND wcp.ssn            = ld.ssn
        AND wla.house_id        = wcp.id
        AND wla.house_key_nbr  = ld.ld_ln_id
        AND ld.status_code in ('V','W');
```

Once i have loaded into the table_A then i created a cursor to find out the records having the sum of split not equal to 100. For those cases I will find the diff and then update the record as given below.

```
CURSOR max_percent IS                                                     
   SELECT house_id,                                                           
          house_key_nbr,                                                     
          sum(split) percent_sum                                     
     FROM TABLE_A s1,                             
          TABLE_D p1,                                            
          table_C c1                                               
    WHERE s1.house_id = p1.id                                           
      AND p1.ev_id = c1.ev_id                                            
      AND c1.conv_id = I_conv_id                                       
    GROUP BY house_id, house_key_nbr                                    
   HAVING SUM(split) != 100;         
         
     OPEN max_percent;

     l_debug_msg:='Cursor Opened';
     
     FETCH max_percent BULK COLLECT INTO mnty_rec;  
     
     l_debug_msg:='Fetching the values from cursor';
     
     FOR i    IN 1..mnty_rec.COUNT
     LOOP
         v_diff := 100.00 - mnty_rec(i).percent_sum; 
         l_debug_msg:='The difference is '||v_diff||' for the house_id : '||mnty_rec(i).house_id;

         UPDATE work_conv_part_loan_mnty_splt wcplms       
            SET split        = split + v_diff       
          WHERE wcplms.house_id       = mnty_rec(i).house_id                 
            AND wcplms.house_key_nbr = mnty_rec(i).house_key_nbr              
            AND rownum = 1;  

         l_debug_msg:='Updated the percentage value for the house_id'||mnty_rec(i).house_id ; 
     END LOOP;
     CLOSE max_percent;
```

The question here is, I achieved this simple process using a cursor. Is there any way I can achieve it during the insertion time itself instead of writing the cursor?

Comment: Please post your table definitions and sample data as text **no images** even better description and inserts or a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) . Also then post the expected output for that data, also as text.

Answer (score 1):

I'm simplifying a bit your setup with two tables: `table_a` accumulation the data and `table_b` containing new data.

```
-- TABLE_A: Primary Key  HOUSE_ID, HOUSE_KEY_NBR
create table table_a as
select 1 house_id, 1 house_key_nbr, 90 split from dual union all
select 1 house_id, 2 house_key_nbr, 30 split from dual union all
select 1 house_id, 3 house_key_nbr, 100 split from dual;

-- TABLE_B: new data
create table table_b as
select 1 house_id, 1 house_key_nbr, 5 split from dual union all
select 1 house_id, 1 house_key_nbr, 5 split from dual union all
select 1 house_id, 4 house_key_nbr, 50 split from dual union all
select 1 house_id, 4 house_key_nbr, 40 split from dual union all
select 1 house_id, 5 house_key_nbr, 100 split from dual;
```

The important point is that the `table_a` has the primary key defined, so you need to update only one row for the correction of the `SPLIT`

The first step is simple to `MERGE` the new data

```
MERGE INTO table_a a
USING (select HOUSE_ID, HOUSE_KEY_NBR, sum(SPLIT) SPLIT
       from table_b
       group by HOUSE_ID, HOUSE_KEY_NBR) b
ON (a.HOUSE_ID = b.HOUSE_ID and a.HOUSE_KEY_NBR = b.HOUSE_KEY_NBR)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  update SET a.SPLIT = a.SPLIT + b.SPLIT
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  insert (HOUSE_ID, HOUSE_KEY_NBR, SPLIT)
  values (b.HOUSE_ID, b.HOUSE_KEY_NBR, b.SPLIT)
```

So basically you first aggregates the new data to the level of the PK and than using the `MERGE` either insert or update the `table_a`

In the second step perform the correction using the same approach with  `MERGE` only use a different source table containing only the defference of the SPLIT to 100.

```
MERGE INTO table_a a
USING (select HOUSE_ID, HOUSE_KEY_NBR, 100 - sum(SPLIT)  SPLIT
       from table_a
       group by HOUSE_ID, HOUSE_KEY_NBR 
       having sum(SPLIT) != 100) b
ON (a.HOUSE_ID = b.HOUSE_ID and a.HOUSE_KEY_NBR = b.HOUSE_KEY_NBR)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  update SET a.SPLIT = a.SPLIT + b.SPLIT
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  insert (HOUSE_ID, HOUSE_KEY_NBR, SPLIT)
  values (b.HOUSE_ID, b.HOUSE_KEY_NBR, b.SPLIT)
```

After this step all `SPLIT` are equal 100

```
select HOUSE_ID, HOUSE_KEY_NBR,   sum(SPLIT)
from table_a
group by HOUSE_ID, HOUSE_KEY_NBR
order by 1,2;

  HOUSE_ID HOUSE_KEY_NBR SUM(SPLIT)
---------- ------------- ----------
         1             1        100
         1             2        100
         1             3        100
         1             4        100
         1             5        100
```

If you do not want to `MERGE` in `table_a` and you use `INSERT` only, I'd challange this desing, because it is not clear which of the many records with the same key you want to update.

I'll recomend not to `UPDATE` but to `INSERT` additional rows with the calculated differece SPLIT.

Answer (score 1):

If `mnty_code` is unique for each `house_id`, `house_key_nbr` pair, then you can use window functions in your insert.  Try using this for inserting into the `split` column:

```
        CASE WHEN 1 = ROWNUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY wcp.id, ld.ld_ln_id ORDER BY mnty_code DESC ) THEN
          -- This is the last row for the given house_id / house_key_nbr, so do special split calculation
          100 - SUM(ROUND((ld.ld_ln_bal/wla.LOAN_AMT) * 100,2)) OVER ( PARTITION BY wcp.id, ld.ld_ln_id ORDER BY mnty_code ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING ) ELSE
         -- Normal split calculation
           ROUND((ld.ld_ln_bal/wla.LOAN_AMT) * 100,2) 
           END split
```

The idea is that, if you are inserting the last row for a given `house_id`, `house_key_nbr`, then set the `split` value to 100 minus the sum of all the previous values.

If `mnty_code` is not unique within each `house_id`, `house_key_nbr` pair, it gets problematic, because there is no way to identify the "last" row in each group.

Comment: The best answer. Thank you for solving it.

Comment: Well if the `table_a` is *empty before the insert* this works fine.@VimalBhaskar

Comment: If it has only 1 record then the logic fails. Any reason why ? Sorry tried to test it but i am not able to understand @ma

Comment: How does it fail?  What error?  You possibly need to change `100-SUM(...) OVER (...)` to `100-NVL(SUM(...) OVER (...),0`